# Click on link should not wait for jQuery AJAX call to complete

Tags: jquery, ajax

I will try to explain my problem as best I can.

My problem is that if an AJAX call is running it has to complete before the browser will follow a link the user click on. I want the browser to disregard the AJAX call a follow the link immediately.

I have done some tests and found out this:

- If the link points to a completely different domain the browser immediately follows the link.
- If the link points to the same domain the AJAX call has to finish and then the browser will follow the link.

Maybe I am just misunderstanding how jQuery AJAX asynchronous calls works.

What this code does is immediately start the AJAX call which I made sure takes a long time to complete. It give me time to click one of the two links to test the problem. That is how I came to the conclusion above.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>AJAX</title>
</head>
<body>
    <a href="https://google.dk" style="display:block;font-size:40px;margin-bottom:20px;">1. Test link to Google</a>
    <a href="/some-url" style="display:block;font-size:40px;margin-bottom:20px;">2. Test link to current domain</a>
    <div style="border:1px solid black;width:800px;" id="test">Loading...</div>
</body>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
    $.ajax({
        url: '/another-url',  
        success: function(response) {
            $("#test").html(response);
        }
    });
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: i didnt understand the ajax event is not triggering in your situation its not called on link ..

Comment: it is not about with jQuery AJAX. It is a server issue. Your backend code doing something for your session and your server can't answer your next request before running job done.

Comment: @himyata You are correct. It was the backend. The session was locked. Using `session_write_close()` in PHP resolved the issue. I just had to make sure the AJAX call did not need to write anything to the session.